# How to split string after second white space in php/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$string="112*1/25 5*112/20 456*8/20 2*569/20 156*3/40 9*789/20";
```

I am trying to split string after second white space. How to achieve this? I tried using following approach.

```php
    $my_array=preg_match('/^([^ ]+ +[^ ]+) +(.*)$/', '$string', $split);
```

I am getting output as 1.
My desired output must be look like below

```php
    $split=array([0]=>112*1/25 5*112/20 [1]=>456*8/20 2*569/20 [2]=>156*3/40 9*789/20);
```

Comment: `preg_match` __does not__ return array.

Comment: I used preg_split, 

    return $my_array=preg_split('/^([^ ]+ +[^ ]+) +(.*)$/', $string);
    
but I am getting output as empty.

Comment: Single quotes round `'$string'` will give you a value of `$string`, you don't need quotes at all!

Answer (score 2):

You can try it:

```
$string="112*1/25 5*112/20 456*8/20 2*569/20 156*3/40 9*789/20";

$split = array_map(
    function($value) {
        return implode(' ', $value);
    },
    array_chunk(explode(' ', $string), 2)
);

var_dump($split);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$string="112*1/25 5*112/20 456*8/20 2*569/20 156*3/40 9*789/20";
$arr = array_chunk(explode(' ',$string),2);
$res = array_map(function($v){ return implode(' ',$v);}, $arr);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/FLTom

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$string="112*1/25 5*112/20 456*8/20 2*569/20 156*3/40 9*789/20";

$r = preg_match_all('~[^ ]+ [^ ]+~',$string, $match);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($match[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "112*1/25 5*112/20"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "456*8/20 2*569/20"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "156*3/40 9*789/20"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

        $string="112*1/25 5*112/20 456*8/20 2*569/20 156*3/40 9*789/20";
       $array1=(explode(" ", $string));
       $new_array=array_chunk($array1, 2);
       $n=count($new_array);
       for ($i=0; $i < $n ; $i++) { 
           $str_arr[] = implode(" ", $new_array[$i]);
        }



    print_r($str_arr);
    ?>
```